# AVPlayer Inside A UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, avplayer, ios11, avkit

So I have a view on my HomeViewController that I want to play a video inside of. on viewDidLoad() I am calling playVideo() here is my code:

```
func playVideo() {
    guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType: "mov") else {
        debugPrint("video.mov not found.")
        return
    }

    let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
    let avPlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    avPlayerController.player = avPlayer
    avPlayerController.view.frame = playerView.bounds
    avPlayerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
    avPlayerController.player?.play()
    playerView.addSubview(avPlayerController.view)
    playerView.bringSubview(toFront: QRButton)
}
```

All I get is a black background and no video. What am I doing wrong? I have tried to solve this for a while now.

iOS: 11.2 beta 
Xcode: 9.2 beta

Comment: PS: I tried with Xcode 9.1 and iOS 11.1 and it is the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `avPlayer` as a class variable, maybe it has been released before it can start to play.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
     var avPlayer:AVPlayer?

    func playVideo() {
    guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType: "mov") else {
        debugPrint("video.mov not found.")
        return
    }

    avPlayer? = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
    let avPlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    avPlayerController.player = avPlayer
    avPlayerController.view.frame = playerView.bounds
    avPlayerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
    avPlayerController.player?.play()
    playerView.addSubview(avPlayerController.view)
    playerView.bringSubview(toFront: QRButton)
 }
}
```